# Grails GORM (Hibernate) error with Oracle Encoding Character UTF-8 , Kurdish Language

Tags: oracle, utf-8, grails-orm, arabic

Grails GORM (Hibernate) problem with Oracle Encoding Character UTF-8 , Kurdish Language( Arabic).
I have used grails in my application and connect to Oracle Database. 
Everything is working fine except Kurdish ( Arabic Like) Language encoding.
I have input directly to Oracle using PL SQL for the column data type nvarchar & nclob it is working fine but when using my rest api it store with corrupted for example :
parameter  (description ) : لەکاتی بەشدار یکردنت لە یەكێك لە پاكێجەكانی Speedoo3. 9G باشترین وخێراترین ئینتەرنێت لە عێراق، بێخەم بە باڵانسەكەت پارێزراوە هەر كە پاكێجی ئینتەرنێتەكەت تەواو بوو ئەوا ئینتەرنێتەكەت رادەگیرێت و باڵانسەكەت دەپارێزرێت.

ئێستا و تەنها لە ئاسیاسێڵەوە، دەتوانیت کۆنترۆڵى بەکارهێنانى ئینتەرنێت بکەیت لە کاتى بەشداربونت لە پاکێجەکانى ئینتەرنێت Speedoo 3.9G، و لە کاتى تەواوبونى پاکێجەکە، ئینتەرنێتەکەت هەڵدەپەسێردرێت بۆ پاراستنى باڵانسەکەت تا ئەو کاتەى کە پەیوەندى دەکەیت بە #299* و دووبارە بەشدارى دەکەیتەوە لە یەکێک لە پاکێجەکانى ئینەرنێت... لەگەڵ ئاسیاسێڵ باڵانست پارێزراوە

---

and become : ل?کاتي ب?شدار يکردنت ل? ي?ك?ك ل? پاك?ج?كاني Speedoo3. 9G باشترين وخ?راترين ئينت?رن?ت ل? ع?راق، ب?خ?م ب? با?انس?ك?ت پار?زراو? ه?ر ك? پاك?جي ئينت?رن?ت?ك?ت ت?واو بوو ئ?وا ئينت?رن?ت?ك?ت راد?گير?ت و با?انس?ك?ت د?پار?زر?ت.

ئ?ستا و ت?نها ل? ئاسياس???و?، د?توانيت ک?نتر??ى ب?کاره?نانى ئينت?رن?ت بک?يت ل? کاتى ب?شداربونت ل? پاک?ج?کانى ئينت?رن?ت Speedoo 3.9G، و ل? کاتى ت?واوبونى پاک?ج?ک?، ئينت?رن?ت?ک?ت ه??د?پ?س?ردر?ت ب? پاراستنى با?انس?ک?ت تا ئ?و کات?ى ک? پ?يو?ندى د?ک?يت ب? #299* و دووبار? ب?شدارى د?ک?يت?و? ل? ي?ک?ک ل? پاک?ج?کانى ئين?رن?ت... ل?گ?? ئاسياس?? با?انست پار?زراو?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a few days, I just found after do experiments with JDBC .
       *System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar",String.valueOf(true));*

System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals",String.valueOf(true));

in your config.groovy , I tried to put in booStrap.groovy but it's not working because it must be set before hibernate initialize connection